# Is a Maximal Cohen-Macaulay sheaf on a Cohen-Macaulay scheme locally free?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay-rings

Let $F$ be a Maximal Cohen-Macaulay module on a Cohen-Macaulay scheme $X$.
By definition $\mathrm{depth}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(F_x)=\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ and $\mathrm{depth}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})=\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$. Now the Auslander-Buchsbaum formula implies that $F_x$ is projective. This result seems somewhat surprising to me. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: The Auslander-Buchsbaum formula assumes finite projective dimension. Otherwise there are easy counterexamples, e.g. in dimension zero!

Comment: I believe this questions can help you https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106568/cohen-macaulay-sheaves-which-are-not-locally-free

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I think I saw the linked question but I must have missed the last part.